# Right settings for exporting FBX with Rigify and morph targets to Unreal Engine 4

Tags: export, rigify, unreal-engine

I've been looking over the internet and testing for days on how to make my character's bones (rigify) and keyshapes animations to work inside unreal engine 4. I've tried different fbx export settings from fbx 6.1 ascii to fbx 7.4 binary and nothing worked.

When I use fbx 6.1 ascii, the animation works great but does not import the morph targets. When I exported without the animation, the morph targets work.

When I use fbx 7.4 Binary, the animation and the model is not visible in unreal.

Has anyone encountered this so far? I've also tried exporting simple bones with keyshapes and it works well. So I think the problem is in rigify.

Comment: You should try again with FBX 7.4 exporter from just released [Blender 2.75](http://www.blender.org/download/), it got quite a bunch of fixes related among others to armatures and UE4…

Comment: You can try using the Uefy addon for Blender. It has tools and tutorials for getting Rigify skeletons exported to UE4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mg75kSkKkug&t=4s

Comment: If you use rigify, I think you need to bake your animation to deform bone before export & import to UE.
You can check the tutorial here. This video using rigify. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJzMurUbQp0