# Morph targets and armature animations to UE4

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I'm trying to import a character mesh from Blender that has both an armature rig with keyframe animations and also morph targets with shape keys. Is there a way to export/import so that both of the animation types work? The armature is applied to the whole mesh and the morph target is applied to the face. When I export from Blender as FBX 6.1 ASCII the morph target works but the rigged animation doesn't, and when I export as FBX 7.4 binary the morph target isn't there but the animation works. No matter what options I select during export/import I can't seem to get both working. I've tried unchecking the 'Apply Modifiers' checkbox during export which is what a lot of other posts suggest.

Any other suggestions on what might be the issue here? I noticed there was another very similar post here that hasn't been answered:

[Right settings for exporting FBX with Rigify and morph targets to Unreal Engine 4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33311/right-settings-for-exporting-fbx-with-rigify-and-morph-targets-to-unreal-engine)

Thanks in advance
LB

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been playing with this today, and discovered something very odd. Skeletal meshes imported from Blender with (apply modifiers off), do not seem to import to UE4. However, if, after it's done importing, you right-click on the skeletal mesh asset and select "Reimport", it will bring in the morph targets on reimport, even if the original file is unchanged.